# Pause other media when browser starts playing

Tags: firefox, pulseaudio, google-chrome

Is there a way to pause other media sources when firefox or chrome starts playing media?
I know it has to do something with `pulse audio` and tagging firefox as `phone` stream so everything else stops. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find this piece of code, which should be added to the `firefox.desktop` file:

```
X-PulseAudio-Properties=media.role=phone
```

More info:http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-automatically-mute-music-when.html

This **mutes** other sources, however, I haven't found a way to **pause** other sources that could be paused.